# CakePhp saveAssociated deep=true not working

Tags: cakephp

i am trying to save an array as the one shown below with saveAssociated and the deep options set to true, but it's not saving the Answer, only the Quiz and the Question. I'm using CakePhp 2.3.1

```
$myarray = array(
    'Quiz' => array(
        'title' => 'Test di Prova copy',
        'description' => '',
        'timer' => '5',
        'days' => '10',
        'tries' => '2',
        'pass_percentage' => '90',
        'active' => true
    ),
    'Question' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'question' => 'Quanti valori può assumere un bit?',
            'score' => '10',
            'position' => '0',
            'created' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
            'modified' => '2013-04-10 13:04:50',
            'Answer' => array(
                (int) 0 => array(
                    'answer' => '2',
                    'right' => true
                ),
                (int) 1 => array(
                    'answer' => '4',
                    'right' => false
                ),
                (int) 2 => array(
                    'answer' => '8',
                    'right' => false
                ),
                (int) 3 => array(
                    'answer' => 'non lo sò
',
                    'right' => false
                )
            )
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'question' => 'Quale tra questi tag Html identifica l'header più grande di dimensioni?',
            'score' => '10',
            'position' => '2',
            'created' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
            'modified' => '2013-04-10 13:04:50',
            'Answer' => array(
                (int) 0 => array(
                    'answer' => 'H6',
                    'right' => false
                ),
                (int) 1 => array(
                    'answer' => 'H4',
                    'right' => false
                ),
                (int) 2 => array(
                    'answer' => 'H1',
                    'right' => true
                )
            )
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'question' => 'Da quanti bit è composto un byte?',
            'score' => '10',
            'position' => '1',
            'created' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
            'modified' => '2013-04-10 13:04:50',
            'Answer' => array(
                (int) 0 => array(
                    'answer' => '2',
                    'right' => false
                ),
                (int) 1 => array(
                    'answer' => '4',
                    'right' => false
                ),
                (int) 2 => array(
                    'answer' => '6',
                    'right' => false
                ),
                (int) 3 => array(
                    'answer' => '8',
                    'right' => true
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

$this->Quiz->saveAssociated($myarray, array('deep'=>true));

Comment: 1) Please try to use real model names, 2) include your associations, 3) why are you trying to save empty data?

Comment: Based off your code am I correct to assume that `Model1` hasMany `Model2` hasMany `Model3`?

Comment: I updated the code above with real one that i use to avoid misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

That data structure would work with saveAll, have you tried that?

```
<?php

$this->Model1->saveAll($myarray, array('deep' => true));

?>
```

saveAll internally calls saveAssociated.

I believe that should work for you.